# Как отключить кеширование сайта?

Tags: nginx, кэширование, веб-сайт

У меня есть небольшой сайт, на котором периодически появляются какие-то изменения. Так вот когда я добавляю туда что-то новое, изменения статичных файлов не отображаются.

CTRL + F5 решает эту проблему для меня, но как быть с посетителями сайта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Несколько вариантов есть:

1. Ничего не трогать. Скорее всего файлы, которые Вы обновляете, через какое-то время обновятся и так. Каждый раз просить пользователя качать файлы заново не очень хорошо – это может сильно повлиять на скорость загрузки сайта, что плохо скажется на SEO (если сайт полагается на SEO).
2. Обновлять метки (GET параметры). Например, ссылки `/css/styles.css` и `/css/styles.css?1` являются разными – браузер будет качать файл заново, если параметр будет отличаться. Работает везде и со всеми файлами.
3. В nginx просписать правила (серьёзно, так делать крайне нежелательно, особенно если у Вас сайт полагается на SEO). Прописать форматы и путь ссылки в зависимости от того, что не нужно кешировать. Вот так примерно:

```
location ~* ^/route/to/files/.+\.(css|png|js)$ {
  expires -1;
  add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
}
```